# Transparent logo overlapping with the header menu

Tags: html, css, transparent

I am designing a header menu for my website. I want to place my logo on header menu such that  I get something like this : [image: headerMenu]

But, with my css, what I am getting is : [image: headerMenu Faulty]

My CSS is :

```
*{
background-color: #DBDBDB;
 }

.headerMenu{

background-image: url(../img/headerMenu.png);
height: 50px;
border-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
width: 100%
}

#wrapper{
background-image: url(../img/headerMenu.png);
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 1000%;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;

}

.logo{
width: 80px;
}

.logo img
{

padding-left: 50px;
width: 150px;
height: 38px;
}
```

PS : The logo is transparent. I don't know why this is happening. Please help me out.

HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>


<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="headerMenu">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                    <img src="./img/logoS.png"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make a fiddle. It happens coz logo dosent part of the background blue.

Comment: Looks like your giving this grey to all elements with *{ background-color: #DBDBDB; } ... Does it still do that if you take off that line ?

Comment: Could you add your **HTML** code, that would be much better

Comment: What should I do, then ? Change the background color ?

Comment: make the fiddle get us the link i think its probably because you are using background color for *{background-color: #DBDBDB;} this one affects all the elements of html try removing that.

Comment: Add background: transparent; to your image/logo

Comment: @MujtabaFathel : Added the HTML code

Comment: because you are using background color universally by using `*`

Comment: @KheemaPandey : I want the background color everywhere except the header menu.

Comment: then on logo use same color purple color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove background Color from

```
*{
background-color: #DBDBDB;
}
```

Make it as

```
body{
background-color: #DBDBDB;
}
```

Comment: I know it will all the best.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Remove:

```
*{
background-color: #DBDBDB;
 }
```

and only apply that to the elements you need (probably the `body` or `.wrapper`).

**Solution 2**
Remove the background of `.logo` and `img`

```
.logo, img {
    background-color:none;
}
```